# Are Jest timer mocks broken in Stencil 1.0.2?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, stenciljs

I'm using StencilJS v1.0.2 and it runs unit tests in Jest. I have the following code but it doesn't seem to behave as expected. Am I using the API correctly?

```js
function ok( delay: number ) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return 3;
  }, delay);
}

test( 'timer', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const result = ok( 1000 );
  jest.advanceTimersByTime( 999 );
  expect( result ).toBeUndefined();
  jest.runAllTimers();
  expect( result ).toBe( 3 );
} );
```

the test should pass but instead it fails on the last expect statement

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```ts
const result = ok( 1000 );
```

...sets `result` to the return value of `ok`...

...but `ok` doesn't return anything so `result` is always `undefined`.

So the first `expect` passes:

```ts
expect( result ).toBeUndefined();  // Success!
```

...but the second `expect` fails since `result` will always be `undefined`:

```ts
expect( result ).toBe( 3 );  // <= FAILS since result is always undefined
```

---

The issue is that `setTimeout` just calls the function passed to it.

If the function returns a value then it just gets lost so this line:

```ts
return 3;
```

...doesn't actually do anything.

---

A simple way to fix the test is to have `ok` return an object...

...and have the function passed to `setTimeout` set a property on the object like this:

```ts
function ok(delay: number) {
  const result: { val?: number } = {};
  setTimeout(() => {
    result.val = 3;  // <= set a property on result
  }, delay);
  return result;
}

test('timer', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const result = ok(1000);
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(999);
  expect(result.val).toBeUndefined();  // Success!
  jest.runAllTimers();
  expect(result.val).toBe(3);  // Success!
});
```